# How do I make dynamic allocations for a program run fail

Tags: c, testing, out-of-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a C program which uses `malloc` (it could also have been C++ with `new`). I would like to test my program and simulate an "out of memory" scenario.

I would *strongly prefer* running my program from within a **bash** or **sh** shell environment without modifying the core code.

How do I make dynamic memory allocations fail for a program run?

---

Seems like it could be possible using `ulimit` but I can't seem to find the right parameters:

```
$ ulimit -d 50
$ ./program_which_heap_allocates
./program_which_heap_allocates: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot map zero-fill pages
$ ulimit -d 51
bash: ulimit: data seg size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

I'm having trouble running the program in such a way that dynamic linking can occur (such as stdlib) but not the allocations from *my* program.

Comment: Tell us under which system you are operating, please.

Comment: This may answer your question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Comment: since you're talking about a test/simulation, not sure how you could do it without _some_ code changes. Modify so all `malloc` arguments are user-configurable at startup (easier) or during runtime (harder), and test with ridiculously high values. Or you could use some macro magic to replace all calls to `malloc` with some macro that returns `NULL` when `TEST_MALLOC_FAIL` is defined and operates normally otherwise; the downside here is it requires a special build.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @PierreFrançois linux, ubuntu specifically

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica linux, ubuntu specifically

Answer (score 2):

If you are under Linux and using glibc then there are [Hooks for Malloc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html). The hooks allow you to catch calls to malloc and make them randomly fail.

Your test suite could use an environment variable to tell the code to insert the malloc hook and which call of malloc to fail. E.g. if you set FOOBAR_FAIL_MALLOC=10 then your malloc hook would count down and let the 10th use of malloc return 0.

FOOBAR_FAIL_MALLOC=0 could simply report the numbers of mallocs in a testcase. You would then run the test once with FOOBAR_FAIL_MALLOC=0 and capture the number of mallocs involved. Then repeat for FOOBAR_FAIL_MALLOC=1 to N to test every single malloc.

Unless after a failure of malloc you have more mallocs. Then you have to think of something more complex to specify which mallocs should fail.

You could also just make the hook fail randomly. Given enough runs every malloc call would fail at some point.

Note: a C++ new should also hot the malloc hook

Answer (score 1):

You can have your test program include the .c under test and use a `#define` to override calls to `malloc`.

For example:

prog.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

void *foo(int x)
{
    return malloc(x);
}
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char buf[100];
static int malloc_fail;

void *test_malloc(size_t n)
{
    if (malloc_fail) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return buf;
    }
}

#define malloc(x) test_malloc(x)
#include "prog.c"
#undef malloc

int main()
{
    void *p;
    malloc_fail=0;
    p = foo(5);
    printf("buf=%p, p=%p\n", (void *)buf, p);   // prints same value both times
    malloc_fail=1;
    p = foo(4);
    if (p) {
        printf("buf=%p, p=%p\n", (void *)buf, p);
    } else {
        printf("p is NULL\n");     // this prints
    }

    return 0;
}
```